# Parse Scheduled Background Jobs

Tags: javascript, node.js, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to make an app which has daily quotes logic and shows quotes. It should picks `random object` in my `parse class` and shows them to user. If users saw the todays object they should be can't see different random object in **same day.**

I made this algorithm with `Swift`. But I think `Cloud Code` and `Background Job` is the more clear and right way to do this algorithm. I researched `background job` tutorials guides etc to made that but I couldn't because I don't have enough `JavaScript` knowledge to do that. Whatever I created `Background Job` in my `Parse server` like that;

```
    Parse.Cloud.define('todaysMentor', async (request) => {
  var Mentor = Parse.Object.extend('Mentor');
  var countQuery = new Parse.Query(Mentor);
  const count = await countQuery.count();
  const query = new Parse.Query('Mentor');
  const randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() *  count);
  query.equalTo('position', randomInt);
  query.limit(1); // limit to at most 10 results
  const results = await query.find();

  const Today = Parse.Object.extend('Today');
  const today = new Today();
  today.set('mentor', results[0]);
  today.save()
  .then((today) => {
  // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
}, (error) => {
});
  return results;
});

Parse.Cloud.job('pickTodaysMentor', async function(request) {
  const { params, headers, log, message } = request;
  Parse.Cloud.run('todaysMentor', (request) => {
      if (!passesValidation(request.object)) {
      throw 'Ooops something went wrong'; 
    }
  });
});
```

I want to get random `Mentor` object from my `Mentor` class and add it to `Today` class. In this way I can get Today object in my mobile apps. First function is working well when I call it with `Swift`.

My server **logs** like that;

```
May 13, 2019, 22:22:45 +03:00- ERROR
(node:41) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Parse.Cloud.run is not a function
    at Parse.Cloud.job (/opt/app-root/src/repo/cloud/functions.js:28:19)
    at Object.agenda.define [as fn] (/opt/app-root/src/build/agenda/agenda.js:74:25)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
May 13, 2019, 22:22:45 +03:00- ERROR
(node:41) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
```

I googled this error and learned it is a syntax error with `Parse 3.0` they changed some function syntax. **How can I fix that?** or **Do you have any suggestion to make this algorithm ?**

Thank you!

Comment: What is the Parse Server version you are running?

Comment: Hey bro, It's on Sashido.com and server version is 1.17.2

Comment: Can you please try to update your Parse Server to the latest version? Version 1.17.2 probably does not have support to Parse.Cloud.run function.

Comment: Current Parse Server version for this application is v3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to go with something like this:

```
async function todaysMentor() {
  var Mentor = Parse.Object.extend('Mentor');
  var countQuery = new Parse.Query(Mentor);
  const count = await countQuery.count();
  const query = new Parse.Query('Mentor');
  const randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
  query.equalTo('position', randomInt);
  query.limit(1); // limit to at most 10 results
  const results = await query.find();

  const Today = Parse.Object.extend('Today');
  const today = new Today();
  today.set('mentor', results[0]);
  await today.save();
  return results;
}

Parse.Cloud.define('todaysMentor', async (request) => {
  return await todaysMentor();
});

Parse.Cloud.job('pickTodaysMentor', async function(request) {
  return await todaysMentor();
});
```